# JavaScript function to link a CSS stylesheet on click

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, stylesheet

I want to link a CSS stylesheet on click of the following link (stylized as a button):

```
<a class="changeView-left" onclick="loadcssfile()" href="#"></a>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
function loadcssfile(){
    var fileref=document.createElement("link")
    fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
    fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
    fileref.setAttribute("id", "mobileSheet")
    fileref.setAttribute("href", alternateView.css)
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}
```

This JavaScript function should load the stylesheet, but it does not, How can I have it load the stylesheet?

Comment: Ok - so what's your question?

Comment: isnt it working? what is alternateView.css ?

Comment: Provide more description, what error you facing and what result you want?

Comment: terminator `;` missing and add some text in `anchor tag` to check.

Comment: `fileref.setAttribute("href", "alternateView.css");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Javascript should load the css file:

```
function loadcssfile() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("link")[0].setAttribute('href', 'second.css');
}
```